# Unable to create Menu in magento admin Panel

Tags: xml, magento, magento-1.9

I need to create menu in the magento admin panel. I am not able to create menu in my admin panel. Here below is my xml code. The following code contains the adminhtml part using which I need to create the menu. Please provide possible reasons for it is not working.

```
<adminhtml>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <pincode translate="title" module="pincode">
                        <title>Pincode</title>
                        <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
                        <children>
                            <pincodebackend translate="title">
                                <title>Pincode Import</title>
                            </pincodebackend>
                            <pincode translate="title">
                                <title>Manage Pincode</title>
                                <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                            </pincode>
                        </children>
                    </pincode>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <pincode>
                <file>pincode.xml</file>
            </pincode>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to your controller:

```
protected function _isAllowed() 
{
    $_aclResource = 'module/acl/path';
    return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed($_aclResource);
}
```

or just `return true;` only to test it.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you did is to create acl.

you have to add menu element as well. please try to do it like this:

### not in config.xml

but in:

### ../etc/adminhtml.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <pincode translate="title" module="pincode">
            <title>Pincode</title>
            <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
            <children>
                <pincodebackend translate="title" module="pincode">
                    <title>Pincode Import</title>
                    <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhtml/url/here</action>
                </pincodebackend>
                <pincode translate="title" module="pincode">
                    <title>Manage Pincode</title>
                    <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhtml/url/here</action>
                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                </pincode>
            </children>
        </pincode>
    </menu>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <pincode translate="title" module="pincode">
                        <title>Pincode</title>
                        <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
                        <children>
                            <pincodebackend translate="title">
                                <title>Pincode Import</title>
                            </pincodebackend>
                            <pincode translate="title">
                                <title>Manage Pincode</title>
                                <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                            </pincode>
                        </children>
                    </pincode>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```